# The primary reference "Google.Apis" could not be resolved

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-dotnet-client

[Using Google.Apis version 1.10.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZltiH.png)

I have manually added all the google apis libraries to my application .net framework 4.0. I can not download it from Nuget because its not possible on my client machine and nuget is not updated.I cannot use .Net framework 4.5 and have to manually add library.

I am getting this error "The primary reference "Google.Apis" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly "System.Net.Http, Version=1.5.0.0".

What can be done to resolve this issue and is there anything workaround. Please help me out. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The [Google API .Net client library](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client) supports the following frameworks

> Supported Frameworks
>
> - .NET Framework 4.5+
> - netstandard1.3, providing .NET Core support

If you cant up upgrade I sugest you try grabing older versions.   I cant remember when we removed 4.0.  but i think if you go back to around 1.12 it should still have had 4.0 support just remember your not going to get any of the new features or any of the api changes.

> Install-Package Google.Apis -Version 1.11.1

beyond that you could just code it all yourself i did several years ago to support .net 3.5

Comment: @dalmto when i am downloading dll's thru Nuget , it is working fine on v4.0 . and when i am manually copying all dll's to my app , it is showing me above error. its same libraries which i am manually adding but not working.

Comment: you need to find a version of the Packages that support the older version of .net. your going to have to go back until you find one.   Copying the current versions in isnt going to work the dlls do not support your framework.

Comment: Ok. I am trying to implement Google.Apis.AnalyticsReporting.v4 in my app.so for this it is also using all its dependent dlls like google.apis , google.apis.auth and other libraries. So , do i need to add lower version dlls for each? Do you have any blogs to help me out here? Thanks.

Comment: You need v1.10.0 of Google.Apis, Google.Apis.Core, and Google.Apis.Auth. v1.10.0 was the last version that supported .NET4.0 - you can see this if you look at the nuget dependencies of Google.Apis.AnalyticsReporting.v4 for the .NET4.0 target. Viewing this package on nuget.org shows these dependencies.

Comment: I am using v1.10.1,I have attached an image of it above section. Its giving me this error i.e. "The type or namespace name 'Google' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?"

Comment: Your talking about using a  two year old version of a library.   If you manage to get it to work i think you will be very lucky it may be better to just create it yourself.